# Set the checkbox to true from other Sheet if it it meets criteria

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I need some help completing this Google Apps Script that checks if the key in Column E has a checkbox and will put true in the validation if it finds it in the other sheet. Please see the screenshots for further information as I'm not really proficient in speaking English.
Code:

```
function replace() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh1= ss.getSheetByName('Validated');
  var rg1 = sh1.getRange('E2:E');
var vA1 = rg1.getValues();
 var sh2 = ss.getSheetByName('Completed');
var rg2 = sh2.getRange('E2:E');
var vA2 = rg2.getFormulas();
for (var i = 0; i < vA1.length; i++) {
for(var j=0;j<vA2.length;j++){
  
  if (vA1[i][0] === 0) {
    vA1[i][0] = vA2[j][0];
    rg.getRow();
    
    i++
    
  }
  
}

}
}
```

edit: validated sheet should have a check on col A if in the completed sheet that person has a check on its checkbox.

Validated sheet
[image: validated sheet]
Completed sheet
[image: completed sheet]

Comment: Why not use an arrayformula with vlookup in the checkbox column?

Comment: None of your ranges include column E.  Your post description does not agree with your image.  Perhaps where you are saying Column E you mean column A

Comment: HI @Cooper sorry, I could not explain it well. I was thinking the Column E would be like a key to check if this information existed in sheet1, then it will put a check box in Column A when it finds the same key in Column E. Remco I can't use it any formula in that sheet2 since it is going to be validated by people.

Comment: It's difficult to tell the sheets apart because none of your ranges begin with row 2

Comment: @Cooper I edited the script to make it reference in column E in both sheets.

Comment: Perhaps you have not noticed that on one of the sheets data begins on row 2

Comment: I do not follow links off of this site except for stack.imgur

Comment: Ill edit the screenshots and scripts

Comment: can you try now? cooper?

Comment: Your showing images are sample input situations? If my understanding is correct, can you provide the sample output situation you expect?

Comment: HI Tanaike, i reworked everything now and it looks like what i wanted at the end is that when theres a new row added like in the middle the checbox should as well. Like for example Person 2 has check on row 4 but suddenly a new data is added before that and now row 4 is not in Person 2 but person 1 for example, and the check is now on Person 1 since Person 2 will be moved to row 5, i know adding a row manually automaticaly move the check to the bottom but in my case im using a pivot table.

Comment: Thanks, everyone for the reply. ill make an updated version of this and probadly just delete this.